# System.Web.Cache and HttpRuntime.Cache memory location

Tags: c#, caching

I have a WCF service which stores a list of customers for 60 minutes using HttpRuntime.Cache

If you run the following why does strings contain the 'string3' on the 3rd time

```
  string mykey = "mykey-1";
    List<string> strings = null;

    strings = HttpRuntime.Cache[mykey] as List<string>;

    if (strings == null)
    {
        strings = new List<string>();
        strings.Add("string1");
        strings.Add("string2");
        HttpRuntime.Cache[mykey] = strings;
    }
    else
    {
        strings.Add("string3");
    }
```

I'd expect:

1st time round: strings object null, so created 'string1' and 'string2' added and it cached

2nd time round: strings pulled out of cache, and 'string3' added

3rd time round: strings pulled out of cache, but before you get to add 'string3' again it's already got it.

Is it shared memory or something in the application pool. Which if you pull it out of cache then change it, it's changes the cached version without having to re add it.

If I run the code another time I'll get another 'string3' etc

Thanks in advance

Comment: It should behave like you expect. The reason why it doesn't is not in this question... How do you test this code? Run it in a loop 3 times?

Comment: no, I've copied it into clean website and put it in the page load. and hit F5 3 times

Answer (score 0):

The `List<string>` class is a reference type. This means that you can have several variables that are referencing the same instance. If you change something using one of the variables, the changes will be visible also through the other variables since they are all actually referencing the same object/instance.

In you sample, on the first request you create a new instance of `List<string>`, add some strings to it and then add it to the cache. So after the first request, the `HttpRuntime.Cache` object will hold a reference to the instance of `List<string>` that was created.

In the second request, you then assign a reference to this instance of `List<string` to the `strings` variable. So `strings` is then referencing the instance that was created in the first request. And `HttpRuntime.Cache` is also still holding a reference to the same instance. You then add one more string to the list. The one instance of `List<string>` is updated in memory to contain the new string.

On the third run, you once again copy a reference to this same instance to the `strings` variable. This is still referencing the exact same instance that was created in the first request and later modified in the second request. So in this third request it will already contain the `string3` value. Since a `List<string>` can happily contain several items with the same value, the third request will add another item to the list with the value `string3`. And so on for further requests after that.

You wrote

> Is it shared memory or something in the application pool. Which if you
>   pull it out of cache then change it, it's changes the cached version
>   without having to re add it.

When you do `strings = HttpRuntime.Cache[mykey] as List<string>;` you're not really pulling it out of cache. Rather you are creating a reference to something that is already referenced in the cache.

So the answer is yes, changes done through your local reference (= the `strings` variable) are "stored" in the cache without re-adding.